# Why is drush failing with command terminated error message?

Tags: drush

Everytime I try to run **drush cc all** in a Drupa 7 environment, I get the following error message

```
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.                                                 [error]
Error: Cannot redeclare xxxx() (previously declared in
```

I am using Drush 8.1.3

Anyone know what is causing drush to fail?

Answer (score 0):

> Error: Cannot redeclare xxxx() (previously declared in
>   This means a function named xxxx() already exist somewhere in the code, and you have defined it again.